# Regex: match btn but not .btn

Tags: ruby, regex, haml

In the process of upgrading an old bootstrap version, I have trouble to come up with the correct regex to handle the various ways in which my classes are written in the HAML code.

Here are some examples how the `.btn` class appears in my code:

```
%a.btn.btn-primary
```

or

```
= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

In a migration Ruby script, I can very easily fix the first version through the following line (`haml_string` is the variable the contains my line):

```
haml_string.gsub(/(.*)\.btn\s(.*)/, '\1.btn .btn-default \2')
```

But I am struggling really hard to fix the second version, especially since the first one has already run. I have tried the following thing (which negative look ahead to see if we somehow matched the `.btn` version that we already fixed in the previous run:

```
haml_string.gsub(/btn\s(?<!\.btn)/, 'btn btn-default ')
```

Maybe I am just standing on the tub here, but this somehow seems non-trivial to me as a casual regex user... any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about `(?<!\.)btn`? Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish otherwise. If you post some sample input and its expected output it may be easier to assist you.

Comment: In general you should be escaping all of those periods so they match a literal `.`

Comment: Yes, I updated the first version already to escape the .

Comment: I agree with ctwheels.  For one, you ARE matching ".btn". so your title is wrong. Secondly, you give zero expected input and output. Thirdly, you give no error.  We're not clairvoyant.

Comment: also: your first substitution is looking for "(dot)btn(space)(wildcard)" which isn't even a use case, according to your input!

Comment: So, sweaver2112, as you might know there is no "error" with regex, only that it doesn't match, like I wrote. Also, everything you need to know is in the first HAML line combined with the first solution. There you have the expected output. To spell it out for you: "btn" or ".btn" should be replaced with "btn btn-default" or ".btn .btn-default" respectively. So, if you would pay a little more attention and not just read the title and the code, you would better understand...

Comment: ctwheels is correct, thanks for the help, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `btn\s(?<!\.btn)` is not working because the negative lookbehind `(?<!\.btn)` is run *after* `btn` *and* a whitespace char is matched. Consider a `btn 123` string: `btn` is matched, then the space is matched, and the lookbehind returns *true* because `btn`  is not equal to `.btn`.

To make *your* pattern work (to some extent), you might move the lookbehind right before `\s`: [`btn(?<!\.btn)\s`](https://regex101.com/r/ssFW9b/1). In this case, after matching `btn`, the regex engine makes sure there is no `.btn` immediately to the left of the current location.

However, your pattern looks as if you want to match `btn` as a whole word.
Thus, I suggest fixing the pattern the following way (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ssFW9b/2)):

```
/\bbtn\b(?<!\.btn)/
```

Or, making it a bit shorter (as already been [mentioned by @ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192231/regex-match-btn-but-not-btn/48195957#comment83364985_48192231)):

```
/(?<!\.)\bbtn\b/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ssFW9b/4). Note that this version is more efficient because it has to match `btn` only if `.` does not appear before (it won't have to check for word boundaries and `btn` that appear in non-matching contexts).

If you want to study more details about positioning lookbehinds, see [the *"Positioning the Lookaround"* section at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#position).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\.)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if a `.` appears immediately to the left of the current position
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `btn` - a `btn` word
- `\b` - a word boundary.